# Nested Accordion in Angularjs with same Scope variable in child

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm using [v-accordion](https://github.com/LukaszWatroba/v-accordion), a nested accordion written in angularjs to display some data. Here is my HTML Markup:

```
<v-accordion class="vAccordion--default" id="subCommodityAccordion" 
             onexpand="expandSubCallback(index, id)">
    <v-pane ng-repeat="sub in subcoms.subComms" id="{{ ::sub.sId }}">
        <v-pane-header style="margin-bottom:0;">
            {{sub.sName}}
        </v-pane-header>
        <v-pane-content>
            <div ng-repeat="item in CityData" class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title"> {{item.cName}}</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body pbody">
                    <v-accordion class="vAccordion--default" id="my-accordion"
                                 onexpand="expandCallback(index, id)">
                        <v-pane ng-repeat="data in item.prices" id="{{ ::data.id }}">
                            <v-pane-header style="margin-bottom:0;">
                                <div class="clearfix">
                                    <!-- some data binding -->
                                </div>
                            </v-pane-header>
                            <v-pane-content>
                                    <!-- some data binding -->
                                <div id="container{{data.id}}">
                                </div>
                            </v-pane-content>
                        </v-pane>
                    </v-accordion>
                </div>
            </div>
        </v-pane-content>
    </v-pane>
</v-accordion>
```

In Controller:

```
$http({
  method: "GET",
  url: "/api/Commodity/getSubCommoditiesOnMId",
  params: {  mId: parseInt(mainCommId)  }
}).then(function mySucces(response) {
  $scope.subcoms = response.data;
}, function myError(response) { });

$scope.CityData = null;
$scope.expandSubCallback = function (index, id) {
  $scope.CityData = null;
  $http({
      method: "GET",
      url: "/api/Commodity/GetCitiesOnSubcommodityId",
      params: {  SubCommId: parseInt(id) }
  }).then(function mySucces(response) {
      $scope.CityData = response.data;
  }, function myError(response) { });
};

$scope.expandCallback = function (index, id) {
  $http({
      method: "GET",
      url: "/api/Commodity/GetGraphDataProductId",
      params: {  PId: parseInt(id)  }
  }).then(function mySucces(response) {
      var data = response.data;
      // some highcharts related code which is working fine without top level accordion.
  }, function myError(response) { });
};
```

Now the problem is, when `$scope.expandSubCallback` is called, the `$scope.CityData` is being filled up for the **non-expanded** main (top) accordion content also. How, we can easily avoid this? Because of this the Highchart is not working due to duplicated ids for chart container `<div id="container{{data.id}}"></div>`

I've tried to use `ng-repeat="item in CityData[sub.sId]"` and then in controller `$scope.CityData[id] = response.data;` which is not working. Is there an easiest way like passing index etc. to do so? I'm a newbie to angularjs and self learning it.

Answered my own question. However, if any other solutions are there than this, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to solve this. I used [ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) directive to check the id. In HTML, I used it as

```
<div ng-repeat="item in CityData"  ng-if="expandedSubId == sub.sId"  class="panel panel-default">
```

and in `$scope.expandSubCallback` function I assigned that id to that scope variable as below:

```
then(function mySucces(response) {
  $scope.expandedSubId = id;
  $scope.CityData = response.data;
}
```

So that the data will repeat if the condition matches. Answering as it may be helpful to someone.